# Hystrix command as rxJava2 Single

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

Is there a way to convert an HystrixCommand so it is used as a rxJava2's Single object?
The main goal of that is calling multiple HystrixCommands in parallel and wait for all of them to finish (like rxJava2's merge method).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can get rxJava Observable from HystrixCommand.toObservable() and use [RxJava2Interop](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Interop) to convert it to rxJava2 Observable and then single. Currently Hystrix doesn't use rxJava2. https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1457